# Woocommerce Change Continue Shopping Button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the "Continue Shopping" button in the "added to cart" message section of a Woocommerce cart page to say "Proceed to Checkout" and also link to the checkout page (/checkout).

There seem to be plenty of plugins and info about changing the link, but I'm having trouble changing both the link and what the button says.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A plugin to change a plugin, that gets meta very quick. Is the problem that you can't find where the actual strings are ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not the greatest coder in history, but try to add this to you functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 'my_changed_woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 10, 1 );
function my_changed_woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect( $return_to ){

    $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' );

    return $return_to;
}


add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'my_changed_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
function my_changed_wc_add_to_cart_message_html($message, $products){

    if (strpos($message, 'Continue shopping') !== false) {
        $message = str_replace("Continue shopping", "Go the checkout", $message);
    }

    return $message;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to get this `add_filter` hook to work and it just didn't. No matter how I wrote the code it had no effect.

After an incredible waste of time I finally came across the simplest solution.
woocomerce -> settings -> products

Change the "shop page" to whatever page it is you want people to go to after clicking the continue shopping button. In my case it was the home page. Problem solved. No `functions.php` required.